# Role Checks within an discord.py event

Tags: python, discord.py

Currently, I have an on_message event that deletes discord links automatically. Before it does though, I have it filter through the author's roles and make sure that they don't have any of the moderation roles before deleting. This is my current implementation, currently, it deletes the `discord.gg/...` links even though they have any of the mod+ roles. How would I make sure it doesn't delete any links if they have `Admin,` Mod, or `Realm OP` in their roles?

```py
serverLink = ['discord.gg', 'disboard.com']
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
  if serverLink in message_content:
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(config['ServerID'])
    RealmOP = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Realm OP')
    Bots = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Bots')
    Moderator = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Moderator')
    Admin = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Admin')
     print(guild.roles)
     print(RealmOP)
     print(Bots)
     print(Moderator)
     print(Admin)

     if RealmOP not in message.author.roles or Bots not in message.author.roles or Moderator not in message.author.roles or Admin not in message.author.roles:
         await message.delete()
```

Comment: How did you define "serverLink"?

Comment: My bad, I just updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

So I mess around with the code, and this ended up working with me:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    self = message.guild
    if re.match(".*discord.gg.*|.*discord.com.*", message.content):
        RealmOP = discord.utils.get(self.roles, name='RealmOP')
        Bots = discord.utils.get(self.roles, name='Bots')
        Moderator = discord.utils.get(self.roles, name='Moderator')
        Admin = discord.utils.get(self.roles, name='Admin')

        if RealmOP or Bots or Moderator or Admin in message.author.roles:
            await message.delete()
            return
```

I change it to using regular expressions, `import re`

Comment: This is using an `and` though, sometimes a user may just have one of the roles but the bot should still exempt that. Although I'll try putting everything into an array.

Comment: sorry, I change the answer, you were correct about the use of `and`. Hope it helps